# Angular 6 : Bing Map not loading when used in angular-component-library

Tags: angular, bing-maps

I have created angular-component-library in Angular 6.I am trying to use this library in other angular project.

Actually this library contains Bing Map only.

Issue is I'm getting "**Microsoft is not defined**" on the page where I have integrated this library.

Following is my library code.

**Bing Map Component**

[image: Bing Map Component]

**Bing Map HTML**

[image: Bing Map Component HTML]

I just suspect that my library is not able to find Microsoft instance to load bing map but don't know why.

Comment: You can't have `script` 's in your component template, angular removes them, put them in your index.html

Comment: Yes agree with you. But as this is library I don't have index.html here. Do you mean to put it in my reference angular project's Index.html file ? I did it as well but It's throws other I mean "Bing is not defined". Bing reference is used when I move pin on the map. "new Bing.Maps.Animations.PathAnimation". It throws error here.

Comment: Yeah, the scripts that you want to load, put them in the `head` of your angular project's index.html file, or install those libraries from npm, I use a similar mapping library called `leaflet` and it has a module in npm to download, pretty sure, nowadays, all javascript libraries are in npm

Comment: I found that npm package 'bingmaps' but it's throwing error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bingmaps'" in reference project after adding in library project.

Comment: Just read their README to figure out how to use it

Comment: might be you are import the bingmap modules in wrong way.  Did you install both bingmap and its types (definition file). npm install -g bingmaps
npm install --save @types/bingmaps

Comment: I installed only bingmaps but not types.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya After installing types I am not get reference of Bing.Maps.Animations.PathAnimation library. I think it's not included in this library. And just for your reference this npm package (bingmaps) is already deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove "async defer" from the Bing Maps script reference. When you specify this the javascript files load asynchronously and are deferred. As a result you are trying to access the Microsoft namespace before it has been loaded. Alternatively, add a callback function name to the script URL.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me try this.